# iframe with src from another domain doesn't display

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe

I have a page that doesn't display iframe content. The iframe is present in page source, but not shown. It works fine locally, but on the server it works only when the source of the iframe is the same domain. What could be the reason?

The iframe is placed in .net user control (.ascx)

Comment: Could you post some code how you are embedding your iframe?

Comment: Look at the Developer Tools Console and see if there are any messages there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The page is https and the iframe is http.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called `cross-domain` requests. The server you're pointing on the `iframe` MUST have this feature enabled, otherwise you won't be able to load any page of that site, even if you're using AJAX.

Read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-domain_solution